# what is the simplest way to check for occurrence of character/substring in dataframe values?

Tags: pandas

consider a pandas dataframe that has values such as 'a - b'. I would like to check for the occurrence of '-' anywhere across all values of the dataframe without looping through individual columns. Clearly a check such as the following won't work:

if '-' in df.values

Any suggestions on how to check for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way may be to try using `flatten` to `values` and `list comprehension`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['val1','a-b', 'val3'],['val4','3', 'val5']],columns=['col1','col2', 'col3'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   col1   col2    col3
0  val1    a-b    val3
1  val4    3      val5
```

Now, to search for `-`:

```
find_value = [val for val in df.values.flatten() if '-' in val]
print(find_value)
```

Output:

```
['a-b']
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `stack()` + `.str.contains()` in this case:

```
In [10]: df
Out[10]:
   a      b      c
0  1  a - b      w
1  2      c      z
2  3      d  2 - 3

In [11]: df.stack().str.contains('-').any()
Out[11]: True

In [12]: df.stack().str.contains('-')
Out[12]:
0  a      NaN
   b     True
   c    False
1  a      NaN
   b    False
   c    False
2  a      NaN
   b    False
   c     True
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace` to to swap a regex match with something else then check for equality

```
df.replace('.*-.*', True, regex=True).eq(True)
```

Comment: This is smart and very elegant!

Comment: @MaxU ty for saying so

Answer (score 0):

Using NumPy: `np.core.defchararray.find(a,s)` returns an array of indices where the substring `s` appears in `a`;
 if it's not present, -1 is returned.

```
(np.core.defchararray.find(df.values.astype(str),'-') > -1).any()
```

returns True if `'-'` is present anywhere in `df`.